# Spring boot low performance on reading documents

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot API linked to a mongodb database.

On a specific route I get the events for a user given (it's parsing a big collection with millions documents); the problem is that I get these documents in >20s but when I use mongoshell I get them in 0,5s.

I've already added an index on the userId (it got a way faster).

I've googled the problem but I don't see answers about this (or maybe I didn't get the point).

My method does a very basic thing :

```
public Collection<Event> getEventsForUser(final String tenantId, final String orgId, final String userId)throws EventNotFoundException {

  Collection<MongoEvent> mongoEvents = mongoEventRepository.findByTenantIdAndOrganizationIdAndUserIdIgnoreCase(tenantId, orgId, userId);

  if (mongoEvents != null && !mongoEvents.isEmpty())
      return mongoEvents.stream().map(MongoEvent::getEvent).collect(Collectors.toList());

  throw new EventNotFoundException("Events not found.");
}
```

Is it normal or is there a solution to optimize the query?

Thanks!

Comment: Mongoshell provides you with limited data. This java thread would be querying/fetching all data present in DB.

Comment: is it gonna change something even if the user has only 5 events ?

Comment: So i've seen on another post some people recommend using limitation with Spring Data Paging API but no one said if it actually make it faster. I am gonna try it

Comment: You have 3 fields on the query. Do you have indexes defined on the 3 fields? Also take into account that the order of the parameters in the query can affect the performance. Mongo has a great documentation that can help you.

Comment: Didn't solve my issue tho; still looking for

Comment: Do you find the problem? I'm having the same issue.